# Error 500 - include(user_id.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream (although code works locally) (Yii 1.x)

Tags: php, yii, include, vagrant

I am running Vagrant locally on my Windows PC, Vagrant is running CentOS and having a weird issue with something working fine locally on my Vagrant box, but getting a 500 error when pushing the code to my staging server.

Within my admin I have the following URL which grabs the id from the URL and uses that within a function to add some rows to a particular database table.

http://www.mysite.co.uk.192.168.0.155.xip.io/admin/settings/bulkclassroom/id/19312

This URL above in turn goes to my 'Settings' Controller and runs the follow function

```
public function actionBulkclassroom($id = null)
{
   if (isset($id)) {
     $model = new OrganisationClassroom();
     $model->bulkAssignTeacherAllClassrooms($id);
   }
}
```

This in turn uses the 'OrganisationClassroom' model and uses the following function to assign a teacher to all classrooms.

```
public function bulkAssignTeacherAllClassrooms($user_id = null)
    {
       if (!$user_id) return false;

       $classes = OrganisationClassroom::model()->currentUserOrganisation()->findAll();

       OrganisationClassroomsTeachersPivot::model()->deleteAll('user_id =:user_id ', array(':user_id'=> $user_id));

       foreach($classes as $class)
       {
          $pivot = new OrganisationClassroomsTeachersPivot();
          $pivot->classroom_id = $class->classroom_id;
          $pivot->user_id = $user_id;
          $pivot->save(false);
       }
    }
```

The code is pretty much self-explanatory and is working as expected when I run the code locally on my Vagrant box, however when I push the code to my staging server online I get the following error.

```
include(user_id.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I am unsure why this is happening, nowhere in my code do I have an include(user_id.php) (I have done a search to double-check)

As the code & database tables are the same the issue can only be somehow related to my staging server setup somehow - can anyone suggest what is going on with this & how I can fix it?

For the record - this works 100% locally on my Vagrant box - it only gives the error on my staging server (has the same code & database structure) - the really odd thing is there is nowhere in my site do I have any includes referencing a file called user_id.php (I have double checked and there is definitely NO file called user_id.php on my local or remote staging server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post all Yii error message logged on protected/runtime/application.log from your staging server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your file points to correct location that you have specified, mainly issue is with incorrect path to your file.